# MySQL Query Optimization (Takes way too long)

Tags: php, sql, performance, optimization

I use the following prepared statement:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        c_members,c_users,c_positions,c_done_meetings
    WHERE 
        c_positions.POS_ID=c_users.POS_ID 
        AND c_members.CLUB_ID = ? 
        AND USER_POINTS >= ?
        AND USER_POINTS <= ? 
        AND c_users.POS_ID LIKE ? 
        AND MEM_ACADEMY LIKE ? 
        AND MEM_SEX LIKE ? 
        AND MEM_GRADELVL LIKE ? 
        AND MEM_GPA >= ? 
        AND MEM_GPA <= ? 
        AND MEM_ARCHIVE = 0 
GROUP BY 
    c_members.MEM_ID, c_members.CLUB_ID 
HAVING 
    SUM(c_done_meetings.MEDONE_ATTEND = 'u') >= 1 
ORDER BY 
    USER_POINTS DESC
```

However this query takes 21.971405982971 seconds to load 111 records. When I remove "Having SUM(...)" clause, the performance is 100% better. Is there a way I could optimize it better?

Edit: (Table structures)

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c_done_meetings` (
  `MEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CLUB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MEETING_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MEDONE_ATTEND` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'E=excused, U=unexcused, P=present',
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`MEM_ID`,`CLUB_ID`,`MEETING_ID`),
  KEY `MEETING_ID` (`MEETING_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c_members` (
  `MEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CLUB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_FIRST` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_MIDDLE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_LAST` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_SEX` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-Male 1-Female',
  `MEM_EMAIL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_GRADELVL` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_ACADEMY` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `MEM_GPA` double DEFAULT '0',
  `MEM_ADDRESS` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_CITY` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_STATE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_ZIP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_TELEPHONE` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_AP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_HONORS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_ESOL` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_HISP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_WHITE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_MULTI` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_NATIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_BLACK` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_ASIAN` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEM_EXTRA` varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEM_ARCHIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `MEM_ID` (`MEM_ID`,`CLUB_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c_positions` (
  `POS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CLUB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `POS_NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `POS_DESC` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ADMIN` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ATN_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ATN_CHKIN` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ATN_FINALIZE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEM_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEM_ADD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEM_EDIT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_POS_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_POS_ADD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_POS_EDIT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEET_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEET_ADD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_MEET_EDIT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_EVENT_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_EVENT_ADD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_EVENT_EDIT` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_EVENT_UPDATE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_REPORT_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ARCHIVE_VIEW` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_ANNOUNCEMENTS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `POS_WEB_CUSTOM` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`POS_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_NAME` (`CLUB_ID`,`POS_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c_users` (
  `MEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CLUB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USER_PIN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USER_POINTS` double NOT NULL,
  `POS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ARCHIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `MEM_ID` (`MEM_ID`,`CLUB_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Edit 2:
Yes all ids are indexed, the SUM(...) >= # calculates the number of missed meetings. # is a parameter set by the user (I just hard coded a 1 for testing)

Comment: What do the table structures look like? Are you using indexes?

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN on the query?

Comment: should be indexed: c_positions.POS_ID, c_members.CLUB_ID, USER_POINTS, c_users.POS_ID, MEM_ACADEMY ...

Comment: With `GROUP BY .. HAVING` MySQL must calculate the sum over all entries, not only the one, that passes the conditions in `WHERE`. For now I don't see a way to change it without changing the semantics (and therefore the result)

Comment: HAVING may be the evil thing here, what happens if you remove having but add AND c_done_meetings.MEDONE_ATTEND = 'u' to the WHERE ?

Comment: Irrelevant to the optimization question, but: `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY` means you get some silly data in the results. Why do you do this?

Comment: I need the sum, it's used to count the number of missed meetings, I might have to add a column in the user table that will just get updated elsewhere.

Comment: @ypercube I use all the data under, if you're referring to duplicates, I just haven't had time to write down all the columns by hand, but that should only shave off a few ms, not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have indexes an all fields used in the WHERE clause, on all fields on which the tables are joined (you need to explicitly state your join conditions as right now, you are getting a Cartesian join), on all fields used for grouping and all fields used for sorting.

The last problem is the `HAVING` clause there.  You are not going to be able to use an index at all for that since it is a calculated value.  If this is a query you will use often in the system (i.e. not just for reporting), you might consider adding a field you can use as a flag for this filtering purpose.  Whenever you set `c_done_meetings.MEDONE_ATTEND = 'u'` in any of your queries, you could also set this flag for the member or user or whatever this is associated with so that you have an easy field to filter on in a WHERE clause.

Outside of that, you might actually gain better performance by getting a reduced list of users or members with that value of `u` in a subselect and then join using that subselect as a table.

EDIT:

After seeing your actual table structure, I can clearly see where you need to add indexes.  I am also wondering why you have tables `c_users` and `c_members` with the same exact primary key.  Why would these not just be a single table?

Comment: Yes, I think I will go ahead and do this. Instead of calculating the sum, I'll just add it as a column in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that pop out at me:

You use like quite a lot.  Try to do something with your php code so that this isn't necessary.  For example, mem_sex has a limited number of choices.  Make the front end a radio button or dropdown so you send a value where you can use = instead of like.

Two, if you add a sum() to the select clause, and the appropriate group by clause, it should run faster.  It's worth a shot.

Comment: The reason I use like is because I want to have the option of leaving it empty, I thought SQL would be faster than PHP, I will go ahead and use PHP to construct the query then.

Comment: If your sql says, where sex like ?, and it's left blank what do you expect your query to return?  Plus, I didn't mean use php to write the sql, I meant use php to assign better query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can denormalise you tables and add field to **c_members** that represent your 
    SUM(c_done_meetings.MEDONE_ATTEND = 'u') >= 1 
But you need to update that field always, when updating **c_done_meetings** (can be done with trigger)

Also try to avoid LIKE conditions. Use = insead (it is possible at least for SEX)

Comment: Like I said in another comment, I use LIKE because sometimes it is blank. I might go ahead and do some PHP query making though.

Comment: Exclude condition in PHP when it is empty always faster than SQL. So if you exclude all LIKE conditions and prepopulate value of the number of missed meetings your query must take couple seconds max.